# What syntax is for (var i = 0, item; item = a[i++];)

Tags: javascript, for-loop, control-structure

In the [Re-Introduction to Javascript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/A_re-introduction_to_JavaScript#Control_structures), the syntax

```
for (var i = 0, item; item = a[i++];)
```

is explained as the middle "item" being a conditional test for truthtiness/falsiness.
However, I had assumed the syntax to be (start; condition test; control factor) with semi-colons between each segment. Here, the syntax is unfamiliar to me in the form (start, condition test; control factor;) with a comma in the middle and semicolon at the very end. Is it equivalent to

```
for (var i = 0; item; item = a[i++])
```

?

If so, why write it using comma and semicolon at the end?

Comment: I don't like this at all. It seems intentionally obfuscating. This is a recommended syntax??

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In that expression, we have

- initialization = `var i = 0, item` -- this declares two variables, and assigns one of them.
- condition = `item = a[i++]` -- this performs an assignment, and tests the result of the assignment
- control factor = `nothing` -- the increment of `i` was done as part of the condition, so nothing is needed here

A `for-loop` is essentially equivalent to the following:

```
initialization;
while (condition) {
    body;
    control factor;
}
```

So when we substitute from your loop, we get:

```
var i = 0, item;
while (item = a[i++]) {
    // body that you didn't show
}
```

An assignment's value is the value that was assigned, so the condition is whether `a[i]` was truthy. No control factor is needed because `a[i++]` returns the value of `a[i]` and *also* increments `i` at the same time.

A more typical way to write this loop would be:

```
for (var i = 0; a[i]; i++) {
    var item = a[i];
    // body that you didn't show
}
```

The author was just showing how you can combine many pieces of this.

Comment: I like the way you laid this out. Good job.

Comment: as a note to myself, i would probably add that the array returns "undefined" once it tries to access an element beyond its length (or unfilled element), which is converted to boolean FALSE.

Answer (score 2):

The format hasn't changed. It's simply declaring the `var item`. So, it is declaring two variables in the `start` section. The truthiness test is `item = a[i++];` and the `control factor` is nothing.

```
for (;;) statement
```

Is a valid for statement. You don't HAVE to put anything in any of the sections.

`item = a[i++]` evaluates to true so long as `item` evaluates to `true`. The truthiness is done on the left-hand side of the assignment. That will depend on it's data type, but for an int, this could be any value besides `0` for example.

Comment: Maybe explain a little about why `item = a[i++]` is true at the right times?